# Finding a certificate if E=NE

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

If $\textbf{P}= \textbf{NP}$ then for every language from $\textbf{NP}$ there exists an algorithm of finding a certificate in polynomial time.

Assume that $\textbf{E} = \textbf{NE}$. Is it true that there is an algorithm of finding a certificate in exponential time for every language from $\textbf{NE}$?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I know the following proof for $\textbf{P}=\textbf{NP}$: let $L \in \textbf{NP}$. Consider $L'= \{ (x, y) \mid x \in L, y \text{ is a prefix of a certificate for } x \}$. Since $L' \in \textbf{NP}=\textbf{P}$ and $|y|$ bounded by a polynomial we have a polynomial time algorithm finding a certificate. However, for $\textbf{E}=\textbf{NE}$ the length of $y$ will be exponential, so this reasoning gives a double-exponential algorithm, isn't it?

Comment: It seems you've answered your own question with the Impagliazzo Tardos reference. It would be good to post it as an answer.

Comment: Bellare & Goldwasser show a related result: if doubly-exponential time isn't equal to nondeterministic doubly-exponential time, then there is a problem in NP whose search version doesn't reduce to its decision version.

Answer (score 5):

R. Impagliazzo ; G. Tardos [shown](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/63482/) that there exists  an oracle  relative to which
$\textbf{E} = \textbf{NE}$ , yet there is an exponential-type search problem
that requires doubly exponential randomized time.

The [similar situation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995885800048) with collapsing of exponential hierarchy.